# Android:Question about cpu usage.

Tags: android

I'm currently developing a music player and created a service in order to play the music in the background. In the task manager of my Galaxy S I noticed that the CPU-usage of my app goes from 0,30-1,10%, and I also noticed that the CPU-usage of the native music player (and others too) is around 0,00%(stable). What's could be the cause of the increased usage%?

Note: I'm not using any multithreading or asynctasks in my app.

Comment: Are you using MediaPlayer class for playout ?

Answer (score 1):

This can happen in case you are using custom multimedia stack instead of default android stack. i.e. if you are not using MediaPlayer class. MediaPlayer class internally interacts with the appropriate media frameworks say Stagefright or Opencore. These media frameworks will have hardware accelerated decoders => low CPU consumption.

However if you are using AudioTrack, then parsing and decoding is on you and it is decoding that will take considerable amount of time. That definitely can result in increase in CPU usage.

Shash

Comment: I don't know if i understand you very well but i create my player like that "MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer" MediaPlayer is class from Android(android.media.MediaPlayer).

Comment: Okay then its not because of software codecs from custom multimedia stack. Anyways could share the code that involves mediaplayer ?

Comment: ok,so in onCreate() method i create my player "MediaPlayer player=new MediaPlayer();" Then i have a method for playing "... player.reset(); 
String filename=position.get(curtrack); 
player.setDataSource(filename);
player.prepare();
player.start();
player.seekTo(progr); ("position" is an ArrayList with route of my song(s) ).

Comment: Are you calling setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC) on media player ?

Comment: No i don't call it, should i ??